# Getting 'list index out of range' error when using a flow_from_dataframe method

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using python and tensorflow and have created a flow from dataframe method (viewed open source code from kaggle) to generate a training and validation datagen. My issue is when i run code for creating a test_X, test_Y sets using the same flow_from_dataframe method.

Originally, this code has worked as kaggle code shows, but for some reason it does not seem to work for me.

I've checked many kaggle kernels, some of which are:

https://www.kaggle.com/digitalchaos666/simple-vgg16/notebook and 
https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/attention-on-pretrained-vgg16-for-bone-age

which both have the same code for the problem, but does not seem to run now. Even if you fork the kernel and just run the code as-is, without changing anything, it seems to fail at that point

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(samplewise_center=False, 
                        samplewise_std_normalization=False, 
                          horizontal_flip = True, 
                          vertical_flip = False, 
                          height_shift_range = 0.2, 
                          width_shift_range = 0.2, 
                          rotation_range = 5, 
                          shear_range = 0.01,
                          fill_mode = 'nearest',
                          zoom_range=0.25,
                         preprocessing_function = preprocess_input)

train_gen = flow_from_dataframe(train_datagen, df_train, 
                        path_col = 'path',
                        y_col = 'bone_age_zscore', 
                        target_size = IMG_SIZE,
                        color_mode = 'rgb',
                        batch_size = 32)

valid_gen = flow_from_dataframe(train_datagen, df_valid, 
                        path_col = 'path',
                        y_col = 'bone_age_zscore', 
                        target_size = IMG_SIZE,
                        color_mode = 'rgb',
                        batch_size = 256)

# used a fixed dataset for evaluating the algorithm, issue lies here
test_X, test_Y = next(flow_from_dataframe(train_datagen, 
                        df_valid, 
                        path_col = 'path',
                        y_col = 'bone_age_zscore', 
                        target_size = IMG_SIZE,
                        color_mode = 'rgb',
                        batch_size = 512))


The error message is as follows: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-10b59388b3f6> in <module>
     36                             target_size = IMG_SIZE,
     37                             color_mode = 'rgb',
---> 38                             batch_size = 512)) # one big batch
     39 
     40 print('Complete')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in __next__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    102 
    103     def __next__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 104         return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
    105 
    106     def next(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in next(self)
    114         # The transformation of images is not under thread lock
    115         # so it can be done in parallel
--> 116         return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
    117 
    118     def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
    225         filepaths = self.filepaths
    226         for i, j in enumerate(index_array):
--> 227             img = load_img(filepaths[j],
    228                            color_mode=self.color_mode,
    229                            target_size=self.target_size,

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

I had solved my issue by creating separate dataframes for each generator.
The train_flow and valid_flow, both make use of the flow_from_dataframe method which takes in a seed value. This allows my training and validation set to be the same whenever I run my code, which was a preference which I needed.

On the other hand, my test_flows did not take in a seed value, so I had created a new method for those.

```
train_idg = ImageDataGenerator(zoom_range=0.2,
                           fill_mode='nearest',
                           rotation_range=25,  
                           width_shift_range=0.25,  
                           height_shift_range=0.25,  
                           vertical_flip=False, 
                           horizontal_flip=True,
                           shear_range = 0.2,
                           samplewise_center=False, 
                           samplewise_std_normalization=False)

val_idg = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.25, 
                         height_shift_range=0.25, 
                         horizontal_flip=True)

test_idg = ImageDataGenerator()

####
def flow_from_dataframe(imgDatGen, df, batch_size, seed, img_size):
    gc.collect()
    gen_img = imgDatGen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df,
        x_col='path', y_col='boneage_zscore',
        batch_size=batch_size, seed=seed, shuffle=True, class_mode='other',
        target_size=img_size, color_mode='rgb',
        drop_duplicates=False)

    gen_gender = imgDatGen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df,
        x_col='path', y_col='gender',
        batch_size=batch_size, seed=seed, shuffle=True, class_mode='other',
        target_size=img_size, color_mode='rgb',
        drop_duplicates=False)

    while True:
        X1i = gen_img.next()
        X2i = gen_gender.next()
        gc.collect()
        yield [X1i[0], X2i[1]], X1i[1]

####

train_flow = flow_from_dataframe(train_idg, train_df, BATCH_SIZE_TRAIN, SEED, IMG_SIZE)

valid_flow = flow_from_dataframe(val_idg, valid_df, BATCH_SIZE_VAL, SEED, IMG_SIZE)

####


def test_gen_2inputs(imgDatGen, df, batch_size, img_size):
    gc.collect()
    gen_img = imgDatGen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df,
        x_col='path', y_col='boneage_zscore',
        batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, class_mode='other',
        target_size=img_size, color_mode='rgb',
        drop_duplicates=False)

    gen_gender = imgDatGen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df,
        x_col='path', y_col='gender',
        batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, class_mode='other',
        target_size=img_size, color_mode='rgb',
        drop_duplicates=False)

    while True:
        X1i = gen_img.next()
        X2i = gen_gender.next()
        gc.collect()
        yield [X1i[0], X2i[1]], X1i[1]

test_flow = test_gen_2inputs(test_idg, test_df, 789, IMG_SIZE)
male_test_flow = test_gen_2inputs(test_idg, male_df, 789, IMG_SIZE)
female_test_flow = test_gen_2inputs(test_idg, female_df, 789, IMG_SIZE)
```

Thereafter, the code below runs successfully

```
train_X, train_Y = next(my_train_flow)
test_X, test_Y = next(test_flow)
male_test_X, male_test_Y = next(male_test_flow)
female_test_X, female_test_Y = next(female_test_flow)
```